# Installing archer gdb

Tags: git, gdb

Trying to install the archer branch of gdb so I can have support for some Fortran 90 feature that will be useful to me that are not in the standard gdb. When I follow their instructions to install on the website, i.e., run:

`git clone --origin archer git://sourceware.org/git/archer.git`

I get the concerning output:

`Cloning into 'archer'...
remote: Counting objects: 800265, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (151929/151929), done.
remote: Total 800265 (delta 645435), reused 795161 (delta 640396)
Receiving objects: 100% (800265/800265), 255.46 MiB | 6.51 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (645435/645435), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.`

I've looked all over the internet with no success. Any advice?

Comment: Pull again as in rerun the clone command? And how do I run a git log?

Comment: Link the complete instructions from the website.

Answer (score 1):

You did just the first step of the instructions. You must continue along the tutorial.

> Then you can check out and track the trunk using ..  See ArcherBranchManagement for the available branches.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ArcherBranchManagement

```
$ git clone --origin archer ssh://sourceware.org/git/archer.git
$ cd archer
$ git remote add gdb git://sourceware.org/git/gdb.git
$ git fetch gdb
$ git checkout gdb/master
```